# Design matrix for getting desired contrasts in 3x3 design with 2 controls

Tags: multiple-regression, anova, generalized-linear-model, contrasts

We have nine conditions in our study (two category factors each with three levels; **A**: *a1, a2, a3*; **S**: *s, c1, c2*). I did two-way ANOVA; however, we are interested in a more nuanced question. c1 and c2 are control variables controlling different (and independent) aspects of s. We want to compare s and controls (s-c1 and s-c2). More importantly, we are interested in the “specific” responses to a1, a2, and a3 after we subtract the effects of c1 and c2.


I am trying to make a design matrix to get desired comparisons/contrasts; however, I am a little lost on how to proceed.   I considered Treatment-coding A with no intercept and Sum coding S.

---

(Probably non-essential) details on the analysis: We actually do the analysis on each time point and sensors. We are interested in which sensors read responses to c1, c2, A (s-c1 and s-c2), and which sensors read a1-specific responses, a2-specific responses and a3-specific responses. We do permutation cluster tests (Maris & Oostenveld, 2007; [a brief overview](https://benediktehinger.de/blog/science/statistics-cluster-permutation-test/)) on each sensor with the statistic time series (each statistics comes from a single time point).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "responses to a1, a2, and a3 after we subtract the effects of c1 and c2"? a1-c1, a1-c2, a2-c1, a2-c2, and a3-c1, a3-c2?